# How to Improve SQL Server 2012 Timeout Issues - Large Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We work for a small company that cannot afford to pay SQL DBA nor consultation.

What started as a small project has now become a full scale system with a lot of data.

I need someone to help me sort out performance improvements. I realise no-one will be able to help directly and nail this issue completely, but I just want to make sure I have covered my tracks.

OK, the problem is basically we are experiencing time-outs with our queries on cached data. I have increased the time-out time with c# code but I can only go so far when it's becoming ridiculous.

The current setup is a database that has data inserted every 5 / 10 seconds, constantly! During this process we populate tables from csv files. Over night we run data caching processes that reduces the overload on the "inserted" tables. Originally we were able to convert 10+ million rows into say 400000 rows, but as users want more filtering we had to include more data rows and of course increases the number of data cached tables from 400000 to 1-3 million rows.

On my SQL Development Server (which does not have data inserted every 5 seconds) it used to take 30 seconds to run queries on data cache table with 5 million rows, now with indexing and some improvements it's now 17 seconds. The live server has standard SQL Server and used to take 57 seconds, now 40 seconds.

We have 15+ instances running with same number of databases.

So far we have outlined the following ways of improving the system:

- Indexing on some of the data cached tables - database now bloated and slows down overnight processes.
- Increased CommandTimeout
- Moved databases to SSD

Recent improvements likely:

- Realised we will have to move csv files on another hard disk and not on the same SSD drive SQL Server databases reside.
- Possibly use file-groups for indexing or cached tables - not sure if SQL Server standard will cover this.
- Enterprise version and partition table data - customer may pay for this but we certainly can't afford this.

As I said I'm looking for rough guidelines and realise no-one may be able to help fix this issue completely. We're are a small team and no-one has extended SQL Server experience. Customer wants answers and we've tried everything we know. Incidentally they had a small scale version in Excel and said they found no issues so why are we?!?!?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: What kind of queries you issue? Do you return millions of rows from your query or few hundreds of single rows or few hundreds of aggregate values over millions of rows? Every such case needs different approach.

Comment: We have 20 main queries varying from simple record counts to data matrix's. It's not the number of rows being returned to the client website, it's the number of rows in filtering the data before being processed to the client. So the filtering of data range from 100,000 to 1million plus, then we return no more than say 2000 records to the client (charts, tables etcs.)

Comment: This means aggregating over millions of rows. Have you considered using materialized/indexed views? Depend on database design these can produce real performance gain - and you can use such views on most (all?) SQL server versions, using `with(noexpand)` hint.

Comment: OK I'm interested. I will search on this. I just thought adding indexes to views would be the same as indexing the cached data tables anyway? But it's "materialized" part of it I would need to investigate.

Comment: You can create materialized aggregating views and index them, SQL server internally creates physical data (tables) for results and updates them on the fly. There are some nasty constraints you need to follow (no left joins, no unions, no nulls, no `max()` kind of aggregates etc), but I think you have enough power over your database design to amend it to these requirements :)

Comment: My only concern is now the number of indexes and how this will affect the database size but still looking into this. This whole process will take some time.